# Pinescript v4 change function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

Why are these implementations has different results?

```
highChange = change(high)
lowChange = change(low)
plot(((change(high) > change(low) and change(high) > 0 ? change(high) : 0)), linewidth = 1, color = color.red)
plot(((highChange > lowChange and highChange > 0 ? highChange : 0)), linewidth = 1, color = color.blue)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your calculations are behind a conditional statement thus they don't get calculated with each tick and Pine is throwing a warning:

`The function 'change' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from the ternary operator or from the scope.`

[image: Tradingview warning]

Comment: Interesting, I'm not getting any warnings for both v4 and v5. Can you share your test code?